# Balance not updating properly after going through add_money function

Tags: python

I was creating this small project for a **lottery machine**, but I am having some form of logic issue in the `add_money` function which gets triggered when the bet placed by the user is greater than the amount he has in his balance.

The function is to add the money to the original balance that the user deposits and that should be used throughout the rest of the program, but it is using the original balance that was present before adding the money.

Here is the function that I am facing the issue in:

```
def add_money(balance):
    choice=input("Do you want to add more money? (y/n): ")
    if choice=="y":
        while True: 
            amt=(input("Enter the amount to add: "))
            if amt.isdigit():
                amt=int(amt)
                if (amt>0):
                    balance+=amt
                    break
                else:
                    print("Amount must be greater than 0.\n")
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid amount.\n")
    print(f"Current Balance: {balance}")
    return balance
```

The input-output causing the issue is this:

```
Enter the amount you would like to deposit: 10
Current Balance : 10
Press enter to play (q to quit).
Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-3) : 3
Enter the amount to bet on each line: 5
You don't have enough balance to bet that amount.
Do you want to add more money? (y/n): y
Enter the amount to add: 5
Current Balance: 15
Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-3) : 3
Enter the amount to bet on each line: 5
You are betting 5 on 3 lines
Total betting amount = 15
☢️ |  | 
 | ☢️ | 
❤️ | ❤️ | 
You didn't win anything.
Better Luck next time!
Current Balance : -5
Press enter to play (q to quit).
```

Here is the entire code:

```
import random

MAX_LINES=3
MIN_BET =1
MAX_BET=1000

ROWS=3
COLS=3

symbol_count={
    "":10,
    "":2,
    "":10,
    "":2,
    "":1,
    "":2,
    "":3,
    "":3,
    "":2,
    "":1,
    "⚡":2,
    "❤️":10,
    "":10,
    "☢️":2,
    "*️⃣":1
    
}

symbol_values={
    "":6,
    "":2,
    "":10,
    "":3,
    "":15,
    "":2,
    "":2,
    "":9,
    "":5,
    "":15,
    "⚡":2,
    "❤️":5,
    "":10,
    "☢️":3,
    "*️⃣":15
    
}


def check_win(columns,lines,bet,values):
    winnings=0
    winning_lines=[]
    for line in range(lines):
        symbol=columns[0][line]
        for column in columns:
            symbol_to_check=column[line]
            if symbol!=symbol_to_check:
                break
        else:
            winnings+=values[symbol]*bet
            winning_lines.append(line+1)
    return winnings,winning_lines


def get_spin(rows,cols,symbols):
    all_symbols=[]
    for symbol, symbol_count in symbols.items():
        for _ in range(symbol_count):
            all_symbols.append(symbol)
            
    columns = []
    for col in range(cols):
        column = []
        current_symbols=all_symbols[:] #we use [:] since we want to pass a copy and not the reference
        for row in range(rows):
            value=random.choice(current_symbols)
            current_symbols.remove(value)
            column.append(value)
            
        columns.append(column)
        
        
    return columns


def print_spin(columns):
    for row in range(len(columns[0])):
        for i,column in enumerate(columns):
            if i!=len(columns)-1:
                print(column[row],end=' | ')
            else:
                print(column[row],end='')
        print()


def deposit():
    while True:
        amount=input("Enter the amount you would like to deposit: ")
        if(amount.isdigit()):
            amount=int(amount)
            if (amount>0):
                break
            else:
                print("Amount must be greater than 0.\n")
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid amount.\n")
    return amount
           

def get_num_of_lines():
    while True:
        lines=input("Enter the number of lines to bet on (1-" + str(MAX_LINES)+") : ")
        if(lines.isdigit()):
            lines=int(lines)
            if (1<=lines<=MAX_LINES):
                break
            else:
                print("Enter a valid number of lines.\n")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number.\n")
    return lines           

  
def get_bet():
    while True:
        amount=input("Enter the amount to bet on each line: ")
        if(amount.isdigit()):
            amount=int(amount)
            if (MIN_BET<=amount<=MAX_BET):
                break
            else:
                print(f"Amount must be between {MIN_BET} - {MAX_BET}.\n")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number.\n")
    return amount       


def add_money(balance):
    choice=input("Do you want to add more money? (y/n): ")
    if choice=="y":
        while True: 
            amt=(input("Enter the amount to add: "))
            if amt.isdigit():
                amt=int(amt)
                if (amt>0):
                    balance+=amt
                    break
                else:
                    print("Amount must be greater than 0.\n")
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid amount.\n")
    print(f"Current Balance: {balance}")
    return balance


def spin(balance):
    while True:
        lines=get_num_of_lines()
        bet=get_bet()
        if((bet*lines)>balance):
            print("You don't have enough balance to bet that amount.")
            balance = add_money(balance)
                
        else:
            break
    print(f"You are betting {bet} on {lines} lines")
    print(f"Total betting amount = {bet*lines}")
    
    slots=get_spin(ROWS,COLS,symbol_count)
    print_spin(slots)
    
    winnings,winning_lines=check_win(slots,lines,bet,symbol_values)

    if(winnings>0):
        print(f"Congratulations! You have won {winnings}")
        print(f"You won on lines: ",*winning_lines)
    else:
        print("You didn't win anything.")
        print("Better Luck next time!")
    return winnings-(bet*lines)


def main():
    balance =deposit()
    while True:
        print(f"Current Balance : {balance}")
        choice=input("Press enter to play (q to quit).")
        if choice.lower()=="q":
            break
        else:
            balance+=spin(balance)
    print()       
    
    
main()
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The balance seems to increase after the user adds more money.

Comment: Are you aware that amt.isdigit() might be True but the consequent int(amt) could fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you pass balance per value and not per reference in your spin method. Your method addMoney just adds the money to your balance that is only valid for the scope from the spin method. After the spin method the balance in your main method has the same value as before calling spin(). So Try to change your spin method like this:

```
def spin(balance):
while True:
    lines=get_num_of_lines()
    bet=get_bet()
    if((bet*lines)>balance):
        print("You don't have enough balance to bet that amount.")
        balance = add_money(balance)
            
    else:
        break
print(f"You are betting {bet} on {lines} lines")
print(f"Total betting amount = {bet*lines}")

slots=get_spin(ROWS,COLS,symbol_count)
print_spin(slots)

winnings,winning_lines=check_win(slots,lines,bet,symbol_values)

if(winnings>0):
    print(f"Congratulations! You have won {winnings}")
    print(f"You won on lines: ",*winning_lines)
else:
    print("You didn't win anything.")
    print("Better Luck next time!")
return balance + winnings-(bet*lines)
```

and your main method like this:

```
def main():
balance =deposit()
while True:
    print(f"Current Balance : {balance}")
    choice=input("Press enter to play (q to quit).")
    if choice.lower()=="q":
        break
    else:
        balance = spin(balance)
print()
```

Comment: This answer fixes the issue though I encourage you to explore using classes.